# How to capture git's output in drush make?

Tags: version-control, drush

We use drush to clone a number of git-repositories during build. Most of the time this "just works", but on (a rare) occasion, a cloning fails.

Unfortunately, all that we get from drush in such cases is:

> Unable to clone *repository*                                 [error]

The `DRUSH_BACKEND` piece of JSON is shown, but claims no error (`"error":null`):

```
DRUSH_BACKEND:{"type":"notice","message":"Command dispatch complete","timestamp":1411582254.5773,"memory":10891736,"error":null,"packet":"log"}
```

The actual error message generated by the git-executable is not shown. Is there a way to change that? Simply adding `--debug` to drush's command line does not do it...

This question may not even be drush-make specific -- the spawning of external programs and capturing their stdout/stderr may be a generic drush thing...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the short answer is: it is not possible. Not at the moment. Although the code in `includes/exec.inc` is prepared to output the captured `stdout` and `stderr` of the command, it will only do so, if `DRUSH_DEBUG` is set:

```
  exec($command . ' 2>&1', $output, $result);
  _drush_shell_exec_output_set($output);

  if (drush_get_context('DRUSH_DEBUG')) {
    foreach ($output as $line) {
      drush_print($line, 2);
    }
  }
```

The only way to set `DRUSH_DEBUG` is by giving the `--debug` flag on drush command-line (it can not be set from `drushrc.php`). Sadly, in a number of cases -- including git-invocations -- the top-level drush invokes a child drush to do the actual work. It is doing so *without passing the `--debug` flag to it*...

I filed a [ticket](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/867) with drush-maintainers and implemented a work-around. We replaced the real `git` executable with a shell-wrapper, which captures `stderr` of the real git (and some other info, like environment veriables) into a log-file, then feeds the captured stderr to its own descriptor 2 -- just in case the caller cares. Then, if the real git's exit-code is 0, the log is deleted, otherwise it is retained for investigation.